# How to blend two Formik forms together such that submitting the outer form will submit both?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a Formik "form" that is intended to be a mix-in into multiple other even larger Formik forms. It is not intended to be submitted on its own, but has many fields used to compute two values of interest.

Summarized:

- FormikA has `firstName`, `lastName` fields.
- FormikB has `x`, `y`, `z` fields and computes `a`, `b`.
- FormikB does NOT have a submit button.
- FormikA embeds FormikB.
- FormikA has a submit button.
- If you click submit, FormikA must submit `firstName`, `lastName`, `a`, `b`.
- FormikB is also embedded in FormikC, FormikE, thus should not have a hard dependency on FormikA.

Here's a very minimal example of what I mean by nested forms, based on [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/42xxjrpz19?file=/src/index.js:0-1609):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Formik, Field } from "formik";

function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => console.log(values)}
      render={form => (
        <Form>
          <Field
            name="foo"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <input {...field} placeholder="Some field" />
            )}
          />
          <Formik
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              form.setFieldValue(
                "address",
                `${values.street1}, ${values.street2}`
              );
            }}
            render={form => (
              <div style={{ border: "1px solid black"}}>
                <strong>Address Subform</strong>
                <br />
                <Field
                  name="street1"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <input {...field} placeholder="Steet 1" />
                  )}
                />
                <Field
                  name="street2"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <input {...field} placeholder="Steet 2" />
                  )}
                />
                <button type="submit">Subform Submit</button>
              </div>
            )}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <strong>Form Values:</strong>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(form.values, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I feel stuck trying to find a solution. The outer Formik seems to have no knowledge of the inner one.

Any way to achieve this kind of nesting of form sub-components with Formik?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to submit the inner form while submitting the outer form but there are 2 catches.

1. You would need at least React v16.8.0 since we would make use of `useRef()` hook (the sandbox you provided is React v16.4.0).
2. Submitting the **inner form** propagates the submit and automatically **submits the outer form** as well, leading to an infinity loop.

> I can provide the solution to the first problem, I don't know about the second one because nested forms are generally not conventional.

Create a `ref` inside your component:

```
  const submitRef = React.useRef();
```

Pass it to the inner `button` you want to click on:

```
  <button ref={submitRef} type="submit">
    Subform Submit
  </button>
```

Now when submitting the outer form **add** this to your submit function to **trigger** the inner submit function:

```
  if (submitRef && submitRef.current) {
    submitRef.current.click();
  }
```

This would answer the particular question of submitting nested forms but open a new one in the sense of an infinite loop. Hope I could help with my 2 ¢.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and the `useRef()` hint. The inner Formik doesn't have a submit button of it's own though. The goal is to have a sub-"form" (not a form in the DOM sense) that encapsulates a set of fields which are used to compute two values that act as hidden inputs, and which can be used with multiple Formik forms.